# Pandas cannot replace NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a data frame with multiple columns, one of them is a date column. A few of the values are empty/null. I have tried to replace the nan values but that does not work since it seems the values are not nan, I also tried replacing empty cells or white space, but that did not work either.

The code I have so far is the following:

```
df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)

df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].fillna(df['DATE'].value_counts().index[0])
```

When I run it and check the output the cell values of certain rows are still empty/nan.

Essentially what I want to do is replace any values in the column that are not dates and instead put in the most common date.

Data as dict:

```
[{'value': 21104.25, 'DATE': '2020-11-30'}, {'value': 17905.5, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 17649.9, 'DATE': '2020-01-31'}, {'value': 17785.76, 'DATE': '2020-09-30'}, {'value': 19771.35, 'DATE': '2020-11-30'}, {'value': 7759.05, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 11937.0, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 16313.9, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 229588.3, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 15319.15, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 15120.2, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 15175.16, 'DATE': '2020-08-31'}, {'value': 0.0, 'DATE': ''}, {'value': 14388.48, 'DATE': '2020-09-30'}, {'value': 13727.55, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 12931.75, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 15587.52, 'DATE': '2020-09-30'}, {'value': 0.0, 'DATE': ''}, {'value': 0.0, 'DATE': ''}, {'value': 11738.05, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 19744.0, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 272561.5, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 0.0, 'DATE': ''}, {'value': 8414.82, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 0.0, 'DATE': ''}, {'value': 0.0, 'DATE': ''}, {'value': 9947.5, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 0.0, 'DATE': ''}, {'value': 332843.35, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 9192.64, 'DATE': '2020-09-30'}, {'value': 9774.6, 'DATE': '2020-11-30'}, {'value': 8593.12, 'DATE': '2020-09-30'}, {'value': 8355.9, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 6544.86, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 7793.76, 'DATE': '2020-09-30'}, {'value': 7560.1, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 0.0, 'DATE': ''}, {'value': 399.68, 'DATE': '2020-09-30'}, {'value': 7330.95, 'DATE': '2020-11-30'}, {'value': 6366.4, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 6366.4, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 0.0, 'DATE': ''}, {'value': 5795.36, 'DATE': '2020-09-30'}, {'value': 0.0, 'DATE': ''}, {'value': 4973.75, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 0.0, 'DATE': ''}, {'value': 4996.0, 'DATE': '2020-09-30'}, {'value': 4996.0, 'DATE': '2020-09-30'}, {'value': 6366.4, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 4052.79, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 4177.95, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 3979.0, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 3428.55, 'DATE': '2020-02-29'}, {'value': 3564.72, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 0.0, 'DATE': ''}, {'value': 994.75, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 2984.25, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 2984.25, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 0.0, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 2785.3, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 47549.05, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 2387.4, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 0.0, 'DATE': ''}, {'value': 1398.88, 'DATE': '2020-09-30'}, {'value': 999.2, 'DATE': '2020-09-30'}, {'value': 0.0, 'DATE': ''}, {'value': 596.85, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 0.0, 'DATE': ''}, {'value': 9350.65, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 8111788.35, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 5347.08, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 652148.55, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 253512.96, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 331942.8, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 907709.75, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 20263.95, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 693140.0, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 398297.9, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 708659.28, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 163875.2, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 65947.2, 'DATE': '2020-09-30'}, {'value': 28776.02, 'DATE': '2019-03-31'}, {'value': 226858.56, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 68511.45, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 271964.65, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 41390.36, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 736115.0, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 2560884.4, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 231508.76, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 1412.32, 'DATE': '2019-03-31'}, {'value': 52480.6, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 544781.68, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 10415.86, 'DATE': '2019-03-31'}, {'value': 7367.5, 'DATE': '2018-12-31'}, {'value': 72381.4, 'DATE': '2019-03-31'}, {'value': 882.7, 'DATE': '2019-03-31'}, {'value': 748250.95, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 64658.75, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 1188.24, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 7791.5, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 4738.56, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 15447.12, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 1070129.55, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 282943.98, 'DATE': '2020-05-31'}, {'value': 115608.52, 'DATE': '2019-05-31'}, {'value': 17229.48, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 443459.55, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 754976.88, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 478217.12, 'DATE': '2020-09-30'}, {'value': 9709.7, 'DATE': '2019-03-31'}, {'value': 147637.35, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 1598.72, 'DATE': '2020-09-30'}, {'value': 54207.9, 'DATE': '2020-05-31'}, {'value': 49936.45, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 311921.68, 'DATE': '2019-10-31'}, {'value': 418375.36, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 4993.82, 'DATE': '2019-10-31'}, {'value': 2049185.0, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 94501.25, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 89925.4, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 468579.72, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 106239.3, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 78337.28, 'DATE': '2020-09-30'}, {'value': 15518.1, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 38598.0, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 1112201.37, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 69944.0, 'DATE': '2020-09-30'}, {'value': 226803.0, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 105244.55, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 20263.95, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 244904.31, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 16673.81, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 224254.38, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 2649.11, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 3602930.31, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 27270.25, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 458158.26, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 198950.0, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 4237038.15, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 11141.2, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 231588.0, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 241623.48, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 2122.89, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 609383.85, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 247413.18, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 4072281.99, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 6323615.24, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 32577.6, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 149176.3, 'DATE': '2019-03-31'}, {'value': 77380289.92, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 36629480.3, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 510265.56, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 411261.69, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 141169.6, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 522033.44, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 34222144.74, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 801665.92, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 89496.18, 'DATE': '2020-05-31'}, {'value': 70159711.68, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 88270.0, 'DATE': '2019-03-31'}, {'value': 346570.0, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 1447241.28, 'DATE': '2020-09-30'}, {'value': 732401.0, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 70288.64, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 18303.4, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 7980879.25, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 11868885.0, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 497409.36, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 4039616.24, 'DATE': '2019-10-31'}, {'value': 2237852.0, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 75594840.0, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 1293389.0, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 1989.5, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 266519.19, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 4163465.94, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 356472.0, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 738765.72, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 653703.59, 'DATE': '2019-05-31'}, {'value': 9299166.24, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 10738127.3, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 547976.68, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 1923196.5, 'DATE': '2020-04-30'}, {'value': 214081.24, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 2597491.2, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 980.55, 'DATE': '2020-01-31'}, {'value': 59994.55, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 49360.0, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 105951.4, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 1056939.48, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 38212.02, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 2697304.8, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 92204.48, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 299327.49, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 29093242.5, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 345545.82, 'DATE': '2020-01-31'}, {'value': 49212.45, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 7958.0, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 2229303.98, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 62787.78, 'DATE': '2020-10-31'}, {'value': 6863775.0, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 219428.32, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 39968.0, 'DATE': '2020-09-30'}, {'value': 102894.0, 'DATE': '2020-07-31'}, {'value': 220834.5, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 219622.62, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 61893.0, 'DATE': '2019-08-31'}, {'value': 1182480.0, 'DATE': '2020-08-31'}, {'value': 165947.6, 'DATE': '2019-03-31'}, {'value': 106723.47, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 237648.0, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 1047381.66, 'DATE': '2020-05-31'}, {'value': 8644980.91, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 44001.72, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 632814.21, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 19045854.26, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 203165.76, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 19984.0, 'DATE': '2020-09-30'}, {'value': 128726.0, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 1644719.65, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 2001865.86, 'DATE': '2020-05-31'}, {'value': 243912.7, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 102847.8, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 133762.2, 'DATE': '2020-07-31'}, {'value': 99568.56, 'DATE': '2019-03-31'}, {'value': 4824.75, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 158255.24, 'DATE': '2020-08-31'}, {'value': 19299.0, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 3580702.1, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 6544.86, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 317082.57, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 12280064.32, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 83950.65, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 2198.24, 'DATE': '2020-09-30'}, {'value': 7805746.6, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 225991.29, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 2680055.45, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 15795.2, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 245432.25, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 100604.32, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 1138641.0, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 24868.75, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 1776577.6, 'DATE': '2020-09-30'}, {'value': 325283.25, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 322256.22, 'DATE': '2019-08-31'}, {'value': 1379095.5, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 3406288.0, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 443877.0, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 424957.4, 'DATE': '2018-12-31'}, {'value': 1177239.0, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 4188866.23, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 978436.1, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 134073.08, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 886828.53, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 763567.0, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 4069722.0, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 201288.57, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 157952.0, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 24029570.88, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 352399.74, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 47549.05, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 910191.84, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 414156.54, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 311946.18, 'DATE': '2019-03-31'}, {'value': 13007.28, 'DATE': '2020-08-31'}, {'value': 1362691.0, 'DATE': '2019-11-30'}, {'value': 1998.4, 'DATE': '2020-09-30'}, {'value': 812675.52, 'DATE': '2020-07-31'}, {'value': 3030207.45, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 395683.92, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 26752.44, 'DATE': '2020-07-31'}, {'value': 3211450.9, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 399682.29, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 23277.15, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 903772.17, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 240284.48, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 1130149.44, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 268582.5, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 5743.16, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 203025.48, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 240024.48, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 1829660.56, 'DATE': '2019-03-31'}, {'value': 103155.0, 'DATE': '2019-08-31'}, {'value': 8105.58, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 1675153.2, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 37416.0, 'DATE': '2020-07-31'}, {'value': 1085869.1, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 581478.87, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 200541.6, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 116051.44, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 274238.79, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 220851.54, 'DATE': '2019-03-31'}, {'value': 363879.55, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 254854.95, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 2533747.52, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 78976.0, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 115643.52, 'DATE': '2020-05-31'}, {'value': 2270560.0, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 2080217.0, 'DATE': '2019-05-31'}, {'value': 343229.09, 'DATE': '2019-10-31'}, {'value': 5141446.59, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 70001.25, 'DATE': '2019-11-30'}, {'value': 516909.12, 'DATE': '2019-03-31'}, {'value': 4053294.13, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 1625168.79, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 3116600.0, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 104448.75, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 202639.5, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 451218.6, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 194787.5, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 12931.75, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 186996.0, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 237546.3, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 58889.2, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 31322855.97, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 2678701.2, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 2229539.04, 'DATE': '2020-05-31'}, {'value': 4868916.0, 'DATE': '2019-08-31'}, {'value': 75255.2, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 1421637.09, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 91409.4, 'DATE': '2020-05-31'}, {'value': 317339.0, 'DATE': '2019-11-30'}, {'value': 3847698.0, 'DATE': '2020-05-31'}, {'value': 22067.5, 'DATE': '2019-03-31'}, {'value': 317339.0, 'DATE': '2019-11-30'}, {'value': 49008.0, 'DATE': '2018-10-31'}, {'value': 559429.7, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 598656.0, 'DATE': '2020-07-31'}, {'value': 2252909.8, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 766839.43, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 760766.58, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 222993.04, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 61756.8, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 1168725.0, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 126022.47, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 439824.21, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 198.95, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 1584320.0, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 6897269.61, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 108626.7, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 4177.95, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 11261159.49, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 3087840.0, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 4138557.9, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 13582471.5, 'DATE': '2020-02-29'}, {'value': 1977953.92, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 197.44, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 637469.04, 'DATE': '2019-04-30'}, {'value': 4617529.28, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 307608.42, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 32075.07, 'DATE': '2019-07-31'}, {'value': 3128886.65, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 4245.78, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 303991.4, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 4236.96, 'DATE': '2019-03-31'}, {'value': 25867.78, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 68246.28, 'DATE': '2020-01-31'}, {'value': 2804940.0, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 136636.92, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 253781.85, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 28562.52, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 59140.9, 'DATE': '2019-03-31'}, {'value': 30106.44, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 237944.2, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 95257.24, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 7791.5, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 18699.6, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 4626356.28, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 140608.4, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 256869.44, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 574316.0, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 221745.51, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 45969.85, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 12833.6, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 13425.92, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 97459.95, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 1270205.3, 'DATE': '2019-03-31'}, {'value': 653551.02, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 2068852.8, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 142619.61, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 234363.1, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 88848.0, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 1008565.74, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 32472420.05, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 117596.7, 'DATE': '2019-08-31'}, {'value': 1718928.0, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 560988.0, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 11846.4, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 1558.3, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 397701.05, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 11874869.32, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 511589.89, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 1558.3, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 77196.0, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 2070310.16, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 441072.15, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 2029997.41, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 746412.76, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 268582.5, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 358110.0, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 380069.37, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 216341.79, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 12440.4, 'DATE': '2020-11-30'}, {'value': 54296.0, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 22000.86, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 484475.47, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 13006231.42, 'DATE': '2019-03-31'}, {'value': 140972.16, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 559671.0, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 1157.94, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 7921.6, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 6910.4, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 618334.83, 'DATE': '2020-01-31'}, {'value': 29616.0, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 350947.8, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 2648276.54, 'DATE': '2019-03-31'}, {'value': 4541.12, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 3067669.38, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 231569.0, 'DATE': '2020-08-31'}, {'value': 1580657.75, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 362685.85, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 1108748.35, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 2648.1, 'DATE': '2019-03-31'}, {'value': 493089.45, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 344851.79, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 48543.8, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 12004.72, 'DATE': '2019-03-31'}, {'value': 792.16, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 776118.76, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 2481702.3, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 215827.2, 'DATE': '2020-09-30'}, {'value': 17427.52, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 4674.9, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 4363.24, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 420835.0, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 519722.07, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 202594.92, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 166410.0, 'DATE': '2020-04-30'}, {'value': 83524.88, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 37249.94, 'DATE': '2019-03-31'}, {'value': 59824.32, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 15535.52, 'DATE': '2019-03-31'}, {'value': 4674.9, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 789760.0, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 6437374.44, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 114067.56, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 2557900.15, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 61403.84, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 298446.28, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 2299464.1, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 235833.78, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 238938.95, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 10284.78, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 548284.59, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 36720.32, 'DATE': '2019-03-31'}, {'value': 1869.96, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 2101309.9, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 1299939.3, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 89928.0, 'DATE': '2020-09-30'}, {'value': 153648.38, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 18889.78, 'DATE': '2019-03-31'}, {'value': 10284.78, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 976430.78, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 177696.0, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 202133.46, 'DATE': '2019-07-31'}, {'value': 168094.29, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 2785.3, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 225369.52, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 109548.49, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 247787.2, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 577038.49, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 879297.6, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 88823.1, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 2797.76, 'DATE': '2020-09-30'}, {'value': 1584.32, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 4177.95, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 175304.22, 'DATE': '2019-03-31'}, {'value': 2804.94, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 536688.4, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 24123.75, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 129915.52, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 127001.45, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 263210.85, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 325139.68, 'DATE': '2020-09-30'}, {'value': 232584.32, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 59412.0, 'DATE': '2019-09-30'}, {'value': 99575.37, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 74687.13, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 1558.3, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 552239.68, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 82924.8, 'DATE': '2019-06-30'}, {'value': 613515.21, 'DATE': '2019-12-31'}, {'value': 212580.0, 'DATE': '2020-05-31'}, {'value': 478305.0, 'DATE': '2020-05-31'}, {'value': 1062.9, 'DATE': '2020-05-31'}, {'value': 817484.18, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 762320.36, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 40585.8, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 236750.5, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}, {'value': 409365.41, 'DATE': '2020-03-31'}, {'value': 56302.85, 'DATE': '2020-06-30'}]
```

Comment: Is it possible that the value is literally just `nan` as a string?

Comment: When I look at in a csv, its just empty

Comment: I think I should maybe rephrase the question, its not so much about the nan, it could be any value in there that is not a proper date format . I just want to replace anything that is not a date

Comment: for the sample data you provide, your code is ok actually, it fills NA DATE with the most appeared DATE.

Comment: Why are you filling a Date column with value counts?

Comment: ^^ also, those are strings, convert to date using datetime and replace invalid values with NaT by `df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'],errors='coerce')` its better to keep date as datetime

Comment: may be you can try another way, like finding out which DATE row is not match the DATE format, `cond = df['DATE'].astype(str).str.contains('\d+-\d+-\d+'); df[~cond]`

Comment: After converting the `DATE` column to a `datetime dtype` you should just do `df.DATE = df.DATE.ffill()`.

Comment: for most common use mode `df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'],errors='coerce')` then 
`df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].fillna(df['DATE'].mode().iat[0])`

Comment: Hi @anky, The above worked fine, thanks